# netcore mvc presedence over spa caches angular build and breaks hmr

Tags: angular, model-view-controller, routes, .net-core, single-page-application

I have a dotnet 2.1 web app with MVC working fine. I'm upgrading it, to use an SPA framework. My **goal is to have both routings living together.** The choice was Angular 6, and all is going well so far. I have my razor pages being rendered with the MVC engine, and then, if the route url doesn't match any of the server controllers, it will go to the client app, which is OK.

In my startup class I have:

```
  app.UseMvc(routes =>
  {
    routes.MapRoute( name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  });

  app.UseSpa(spa =>
  {
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "wwwroot/dist";
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
      spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200/");
  });
```

Thing is, that when I have first MVC, and then SPA in the configure method, the hot module replacement is disregarded, not even refreshing the page retrieves fresh content, **it's like if MVC goes first, it will cache the angular build**, and not until you rebuild the client app [with a hash on all files (ng build --output-hashing=all)], and restart debugging you won't see changes. A workaround is opening the browser in incognito mode every time a change takes place.

If I comment "app.UseMvc()" or place it after "app.UseSpa()", hot module replacement does the job correctly and pages reload updated. Is there anything I might be missing?

If there any way maybe to have SPA routing first, and if 404, then redirect to the server side routing from the app-routing module in Angular?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I was using SwaggerUI and I was calling the use of it before everything.
In order to route MVC, the index.html for Swagger UI and SPA, it should be in the following order:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
  routes.MapRoute( name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
  c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
  c.RoutePrefix = "api";
});

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
  spa.Options.SourcePath = "wwwroot/dist";
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200/");
});
```